# How do i train two days a week?

Tags: training, road

I am working in odd shifts and don't get time to go on training ride every morning. My work schedule allows me some free time around evening however due to traffic conditions here I am reluctant to step out for a ride.

I get two offs a week and was wondering how do i manage to ride optimally to maintain fitness and achieve my goal of riding 100k solo by end of this year?

PS: I dont have money to spend on turbo trainer and i ride road bike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think there can be a generalizable answer to your specific needs, other than "find a gym with spin cycles nearby."

Comment: "I dont have money to spend on turbo trainer and i ride road bike."
You might try to build *DIY bike rollers*, it is arguable how useful these are for training though. Otherwise, perhaps you need to adjust your goals.  Training for a 100 km ride is time consuming, in the same way that one cannot train for a 20 km run with only 15 minute sessions.

Comment: On two days off per week you have time to do two 100 km training rides. By the end of summer another 100 km shouldn't be a problem.